# vue js array property of vue model object not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object, vue.js

I have an object  called `post_put_talent`  which is a v-model, inside this object i have a property which is array called `addresses` . The object is as follow:

```
  post_put_talent:{
     addresses:[],
     birthplace:'',
     birthdate:'',
     description:'',
     ....so on......
```

what my problem is i have an input field which is referred through another v-model `carry_address` whom task is to push data inside `post_put_talent.address` like this,

```
this.post_put_talent.addresses.push(this.carry_address)
```

I am trying to carry out this process from an input via `@change` directive and the method is  `insert_in_adderss_array()` , but getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at VueComponent.insert_in_adderss_array (talents.vue?70da:532)
    at invoker (C:\xampp\htdocs\talenthut-frontend\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.esm.js:2023)
    at HTMLInputElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (C:\xampp\htdocs\talenthut-frontend\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.esm.js:1822)
```

how can i get rid of this error? am I doing something wrong?

fiddle here:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mode: 'production',
  data: {
    msg: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    carry_address: '',
    post_put_talent: {
      addresses: [],
      birthplace: '',
      birthdate: '',
      description: '',
      experience: '',
      expertises: {
        expertise_in: '',
        id: ''
      },
      marital_status: {
        id: 0,
        status: ''
      },
      mobile: '',
      photo: '',
      qualification: '',
      sex: {
        id: 0
      },
      user: {
        email: '',
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        username: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    insert_in_adderss_array() {
      this.post_put_talent.addresses.push(this.carry_address);
      
      console.log(this.post_put_talent.addresses)
      // }

    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id="app">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label>Address</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <input v-model="carry_address" @change="insert_in_adderss_array" type="text" class="form-control" name="addresses" />
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**N.B:** works fine in fiddle but throws above error in build mode,you'll also can see it via fiddle.

Comment: It works fine for me too.  What do you mean "build" mode?  In any case, it doesn't seem like an issue with ExtJS in that case, but rather your build process

Comment: @GeorgeJempty
Thanks for your comment .actually it works finally!! I logged the whole object before the insertion. No sooner had I omitted the log it worked for me too. By 'build' mode I mean in npm run dev 
mode. actually there was nothing to do with mode :P . my bad!!